# Artifactory repository is not accessible inside local network

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, artifactory

for sharing our libraries inside our android team, I tried to setup JFrog Artifactory OSS. Every thing was OK except my team mates can not access the repositories thru our local network.

To deploy repository I add this line to my library's gradle
in my *library* build.gradle

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.9.1"
    }
```

in my *module* build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'

def libraryGroupId = 'com.mycomp.mylib'
def libraryArtifactId = 'mylib'
def libraryVersion = '1.0.0'
...
publishing {
    publications {
        aar(MavenPublication) {
            groupId libraryGroupId
            version libraryVersion
            artifactId libraryArtifactId

            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${artifactId}-release.aar")
        }
    }
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = 'http://10.220.2.2:8081/artifactory'
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-release-local'

            username = artifactory_username
            password = artifactory_password
        }
        defaults {
            publications('aar')
            publishArtifacts = true
            properties = ['qa.level': 'basic', 'q.os': 'android', 'dev.team': 'core']
            publishPom = true
        }
    }
```

and *Executing tasks 'assembleRelease artifactoryPublish'...* is successful:

```
Deploying artifact: http://10.220.2.2:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/mycomp/mylib/mylib/1.0.0/mylib-1.0.0.aar
Deploying artifact: http://10.220.2.2:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/mycomp/mylib/mylib/1.0.0/mylib-1.0.0.pom
```

But when we try to get the library it will fail

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.mycomp.mylib:mylib:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
```

in my *project* build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "http://10.220.2.2:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local"
            credentials {
                username = "${artifactory_username}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"

            }
        }
    }
}
```

in my *module* build.gradle

```
implementation "com.mycomp.mylib:mylib:1.0.0"
```

if I change the IP to **localhost** it will work for my self just fine, but the problem still exist!

**UPDATE**:
Repository on the Artifactory web UI screenshots:
[libs-release-local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADYc8.png)
[library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcVuh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can your teammates access this ip? try running from their machines

```
ping 10.220.2.2
```

Then try accessing the UI from their machines, go to http://10.220.2.2:8081/artifactory

If they can not access it, then this is an internal network issue. Maybe you are not on the same machines?
Also possible that you have a firewall on your machine that does not allow accessing port 8081.

On what Operating System you are running?

Comment: thanks @gba, 10.220.2.2 is my own IP address on the network. the thing is I have access to the UI and I can deploy also, my team mates also have access to the UI and even they can download the aar file on their browser but it does not work with gradle setting(it can not resolve the dependency) even for myself and I have to change the IP to local host.
I am using ubuntu 18.04, and i have firewall rule to allow 8081, and I also turn it down completely to make sure, but still not working

Comment: Is the repo configured with maven repo type?

Comment: Yes, I add some screenshots

Comment: Is artifactory running as localhost or bound to your IP ?

Comment: Check the logs. Specifically request.log and artifactory.log. request.log will show all incoming requests that reach artifactory.

Comment: @yashbagarka It's running as localhost

Comment: so for accessing the artifactory UI(via IP) its working fine but with gradle the IP is not getting resolved for anyone, right ? so you switched to localhost and for you its working because its basically your machine only. As @gba suggested please check the artifactory as well as gradle logs

Comment: That's right yashbagarka, I am trying to find out the problem using logs as @gba said. thanks guys